# the subject of "taking an endless pleasure "

Tags: grammar, present-participles

> Next to motherhood, sisterhood is what they value most, **taking** an endless pleasure in the daily, common place society of one another.

Isn't "sisterhood" the subject of the participle "taking"? But I don't think it makes much sense.

Comment: "sisterhood" is the *subject* of the verb "is". The participle "taking" refers back to "they". *Next to motherhood, sisterhood is what they value most. **They take** an endless pleasure in the daily, commonplace society of one another.*

Comment: "Sisterhood is the subject of the sentence. The _taking_ expression is a non-finite gerund-participial clause, and like most non-finite clauses it has no overt subject. Nevertheless, we understand it as though it does have a subject -- in this case the understood subject is the referent of "they".

Comment: Yeah, it is understandable that the subject should be "they" semantically; however, isn't the subject supposed to be sisterhood since "sisterhood" is the main subject of the sentence?